# Stack Exchange site list tiles use old favicon and wrong background color

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

Chess Stack Exchange just [got a nice custom design](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1178/7297); however the [Stack Exchange site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#) still shows the old beta icon (perhaps due to caching, but it's been a couple of days):

[image]

Also, the tile for Spanish Language still has the same blue background as beta sites; its custom design [is a bit older](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/13538) but does not feature that color. This might be the case for other sites too, e.g. German Language and French Language.